# Unable to install LAMP server

Tags: software-installation, apache2, lamp

I can't seem to install LAMP server on my Ubuntu 14.10, I have tried the methods listed below:

```
sudo apt-get install apache2
sudo apt-get install lamp-server^
sudo apt-get install tasksel
```

All methods refused to work.

The following errors were encountered...

```
E: Unable to locate package lamp-server^
E: Couldn't find task 'lamp-server'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'lamp-server^'
```

Also

```
E: Package 'apache2' has no installation candidate
```

What can I do?

Comment: Did you try `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install tasksel && sudo tasksel install lamp-server`? What's the output there?

Comment: `'apache2' has no installation candidate` concerns me.  It's in the core repo's, so I'd be looking at your `/etc/apt/sources.list` and make absolutely sure it's complete.

Answer (score 2):

1. Make sure you have a currently supported version OS. If your OS version is not currently supported, update your software sources by following the instructions in [How to install software or upgrade from an old unsupported release?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-an-old-unsupported-release) and then skip steps 2-6 since they don't apply in case you have an unsupported release.
2. Search in the Dash for *Software & Updates*.
3. Click the Software & Updates icon to open a new Software & Updates window.
4. Select the first tab called *Ubuntu Software*.
5. Under the **Downloadable from the Internet** heading put a check mark in the first four checkboxes in the list.
6. Authenticate with your user password to apply any changes that you have made to the software sources and close the window.

---

Open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install tasksel  
sudo tasksel
```

A *Package configuration* window will open. Select a task by scrolling down or pressing the down arrow key ( <kbd>↓</kbd> ) and pressing space. This will put an asterisk beside the selected task and mark it for installation. Tasks that are already installed tasks are marked by an asterisk. If you make a mistake, press space again to unselect a selected task. From the Software selection list select LAMP server (LAMP server = Linux, Apache2, MySQL, PHP) and use the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key to select <Ok> and then press <kbd>Enter</kbd> as shown in the below screenshot:

[image]

You may need to wait a while for the packages in the selected task to finish installing.

Alternatively run the following commands to install LAMP server:

```
sudo apt install tasksel  
sudo tasksel install lamp-server
```

Comment: I still get an error. Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package tasksel is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'tasksel' has no installation candidate

Answer (score 0):

Lamp-Server is an argument to the Tasksel application

But I paid a huge penalty by using tasksel as it cleans the entire system; all applications, packages including Desktop running under 16.04 Ubuntu got removed including networking connections.

I don’t recommend Tasksel; instead you can install package by package at command level.

Sequence is simple:

Apache, MySQL followed by PHP

Hope this helps!