# Install Win10 Pro 64 bit on Laptop Dell Vostro 3580 AFTER Ubuntu 18 desktop

Tags: dual-boot, dell

I have just bought a DELL Laptop Vostro 3580 Intel Core I5-8265U having dedicated Ubuntu 18 already installed (customized for Dell laptop)

I'd like to ask you two questions,please:

1) Is it possible to install Windows 10 Pro 64 bit from a "regular"- off the shelf-  stick/DVD distribution as the second OS, keeping the already installed UBUNTU as the first OS and having dual boot ?

2) I believe that UBUNTU 18 is desktop version, not server version.

Is it possible to install LAMP suite on my laptop ?

I'd like to start programming in PHP and MySQL.

Thank you very much !

Best regards,
Paul

Answer (score 0):

1) *Is it possible to install Windows 10 Pro 64 bit from a "regular"- off the shelf- stick/DVD distribution as the second OS, keeping the already installed UBUNTU as the first OS and having dual boot?* Yes.  See [How can I install Windows after I've installed Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6317/how-can-i-install-windows-after-ive-installed-ubuntu) for specific instructions.  Alternatively, you could install VirtualBox or another virtualization system in Ubuntu, then do a virtual install of Windows.

2) *I believe that Ubuntu 18 is desktop version, not server version. Is it possible to install LAMP suite on my laptop ?*  Yes. See https://askubuntu.com/a/998495/197910

Comment: @PaulN Please keep diverse issues in their own questions. We try to limit the scope of a question to one specific issue; here you have two.

Comment: Thank you for valuable information