# Server install and more

Tags: xfce

I'm webby. I need to install a server, for installing DB2, but, because of a physical handicap, I'm not able to write fast on the keyboard and that doesn't allow me to install it.

I would like to know how to install a server setting the keyboard speed or, better, having a server with front-end XFCE. I would like also to know ho to install some Ubuntu packages, do you know the program which allow me to select the necessary packages? No sellpack!

Comment: [How to install GUI desktop on a server?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2093/) + [Unable to install LAMP server](https://askubuntu.com/questions/600195/)